# Could not find property 'allJava' on source set main

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

Hy, I am using Android Studio 0.6.0 as of this morning, during the upgrade process I had to switch to Gradle version 0.11 to compile my Android project.

Ever since I get this annoying error which prevents me from building my project.

```
Error:Could not find property 'allJava' on source set main.
```

This property is defined only for the 'java' plugin, but I am using the 'android' plugin in my build.gradle file, so I see no reason why I should receive this error.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this message?

**UPDATE:**
I solved it, it seems this property is no longer available in Gradle 0.11.1, and somebody somewhere in my project was using it.

I found this line in one of the build.gradle files:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

which made a reference to another gradle configuration file, that used this property to make a task of generating JavaDocs for every .java file.

So in order to solve this problem, just look everywhere in your code for a reference to this property.

Comment: What did you do to fix this? Remove the apply from line?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In case anyone happens upon this thread, I did a little investigating into the Gradle Android plugin source.

It appears that the `allJava` property was removed as it was redundant with the `java` property. Swapping `allJava` out for 'java' seems to fix the issue.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/5e71a83f74258b85d7f5306bf743c4d69d6242f8%5E%21/#F2

Consequently, the `allSource` property was also removed, which will break the `gradle-mvn-push` script as well. I have submitted a bug report for that one, linked below.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71174

Comment: You're right, I was trying to upload a new build of my lib and got stuck with this too

Comment: It appears that the `allSource` property was removed as it was redundant with the `java` property. Swapping `allSource` out for `java` seems to fix the issue.

Comment: You can also still add the other values that you want such as `res`, `aidl`, `renderscript`, `jni`, and `jniLibs`. It does seem inconvenient however that they removed the allSource property.

Comment: Oh yeah and there is `assets`.

Comment: darn, gradle makes me sick!